# How to replace soap xml tag value dynamically using cypress

Tags: soap, cypress

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>abc</wsse:Username>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>                 
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
```

In this xml I want to replace the value of `wsse:Username` to "XYZ" from abc  dynamically using cypress ? How to do it ?

Comment: This is the body of a network request, correct?

Comment: Yes it is. @agoff